# Textarea add div for each space between each word

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a string, which is the content of my textarea

Let's say that the content is "Word1 Word2 Word3"

Whenever I add a space I need to separate the first words from the last word and show them in separate divs, kinda like this:

[image]

I would need to show something similar to the user. I did a bit of research, but I wouldn't know where to start. Am I following the wrong path or should I use, for example, a div with editable content?

Comment: Hi @Sean, You need to show what you have tried, So people can look what have you tried and what is going wrong. Remember people will only help those who help themselves :)

Comment: Why use a string when this is a perfect job for an array?

Comment: @Kip because the textarea gives a string as an output, not an array. But yes, the plan was to split the string using spaces.

Comment: @innocent I was asking for a starting point, I don't know where to start.

Comment: I think we need to think through what changing the text would actually mean. If you added HTML (and it would have to be a contenteditable element not a textarea for that) then the user could start editing it, and it would get in a frightful mess. I would suggest you stick to them inputting to a textarea but what you actually show them will be another element with the HTML added.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you so much! That's honestly very smart. I'll try it out when I get back home. Peace out.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [text,setText] = useState('');
const [words, setWords] = useState([])
useEffect(()=>{
  setWords(text.split(' '))
}, [text])
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div style = {divStyle}>
      {words.map(word=><div style = {{margin: '10px'}}>{word}</div>)}
    </div>
    <textarea 
      value = {text} 
      onChange = {(e)=>setText(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
);
//style
const divStyle = {
  display: 'flex',
  width: '100%',
  flexFlow: 'row wrap',
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-wind-1v1vk7) is an example